# send span text to controller through ajax in laravel

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

O have tried the following code, I get the value in the `alert` but I don't get the value in the controller. My code is this:

```
<div class="form-group" id="getarea">
    <label>Location </label>
    <span id="latitude" class="label label-default"></span> 
    <span id="longitude" class="label label-default"></span>
    <div>
        <select name="area" id="address" style="width:226px;height:40px;">
            <option value="select_location">Select Location</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
function findLocation() {
    var latitude = $('#latitude').text();
    var longitude = $('#longitude').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{URL::to('list-property')}}",
        data: {
            latitude: latitude
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

```php
public function addProperty() {
    $locationLatitude = Input::get('latitude');
}
```

Comment: How do you know your parameter didn't get to your controller? Assuming `addProperty`is the function called from the ajax, you don't do much with it other than assigning it to a variable and never using it.

Comment: Also the lat & long span elements have no text values... ?

Comment: You may need to also provide the code for your `list-property` route for someone to correctly diagnose the problem.